# Understanding translations along the x axis

Tags: functions

I think I'm missing something that should be obvious with this; but I can't quite make it make sense yet. My understanding of translations of graphs along the x axis is something along the lines of:

> Going from $f(x)$ to $f(x-c)$ is a translation of c units parallel to the x axis

But when I like at going from $f(-x)$ to $f(-x - c)$, the opposite appears to be true; the graph moves -c units parallel to the x axis.

I don't understand yet why it is the case that when we translate a graph of negative x, then it should apparently move in the opposite direction. Evidently I misunderstand some part of how translations work.

I have tried a few different things to try and understand this; looking at different graphs, [sliding values around in desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sgee6q860u), writing up tables of values; but it just doesn't make sense so far. I am looking for a way to conceptualise this so that I don't run into issues with it in the future.

Comment: For an even or odd function $f$, $f(-x-c)=\pm f(x+c)$ which is a translation to the left.

Comment: Without restricting to even or odd functions. When you talk about $f(-x), f$ is not the function you are translating. The function you are translating is $g(x) = f(-x)$, and what is the rule for translating $g(x)$ by $c$ units to the right? That is $g(x-c)$. And what is $g(x-c)$ when expressed in terms of $f$? It is $g(x-c) = f(-(x-c)) = f(-x + c)$. When you translate, you are replacing $x$ with $x-c$. So $-x$ becomes $-(x-c) = -x + c$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you - that really helped to make sense of this